# How to install libpcap-dev on Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: apt, 18.10, libpcap

First attempt:

`sudo apt install libpcap-dev`

Result:

```
 Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies.
     libpcap-dev : Depends: libpcap0.8-dev but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Ok, so I should install libpcap0.8-dev:

```
sudo apt install libpcap0.8-dev
```

Result:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libpcap0.8-dev : Depends: libpcap0.8 (= 1.8.1-6) but 1.8.1-6ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I need to install libpcap0.8:

```
sudo apt install libpcap0.8
```

Result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libpcap0.8 is already the newest version (1.8.1-6ubuntu1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1377 not to upgrade.
```

Yay! It worked, so now all I need to do:

```
sudo apt install libpcap0.8-dev
```

Result:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libpcap0.8-dev : Depends: libpcap0.8 (= 1.8.1-6) but 1.8.1-6ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Oh. Any ideas?

Comment: I cant reproduce your problem on clean 18.10 VM. So it is possible duplicate of [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Thank you very much I didn't realise it was related to these issues.   : )